# to-do list item does not get added to div

Tags: jquery, list

as one of my first projects i am trying to get this to-do list to work. On Codecademy it works just fine, but when executing on codepen I get no return:

https://codepen.io/HelleFl/pen/OjNQop

```
<div class='form'>
    <form name="checkListForm">
      <input type="text" name="checkListItem"/>
      <button class='btn btn-primary'>Add!</button>
      <hr>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h3>My to-do list</h3>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='list'>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
  $('#button').click(function(){
    var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
    $('.list').append('<div class="item">' + toAdd + '</div>');
  })
})
```

Why does the item not get added to the list? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're targeting **`#button`**, but have no element with that ID. You're instead just looking to target the generic `$('button')`.

Also note that your button is currently inside an (incomplete) form. You'll need to remove the form component, so that you don't actually POST anywhere (which would refresh the page). As an alternative to removing the form's HTML, you can **prevent** the form submission with `e.preventDefault()`.

Here's an updated script removing the form and correcting the `click()` target:

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
    $('.list').append('<div class="item">' + toAdd + '</div>');
  })
})
```

```css
.header,
.form,
h3,
h4 {
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

hr {
  width: 50%;
  color: green;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: inset;
}

h3 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.container {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding-bottom: 3em;
  padding-top: 1em;
  width: 30%;
}

.item {
  color: black;
  font-size 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class='header'>
    <h1>Simple to-do list</h1>
    <h4>Simply type your item and click add</h4>
  </div>

  <div class='form'>
    <input type="text" name="checkListItem" />
    <button class='btn btn-primary'>Add!</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h3>My to-do list</h3>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='list'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: let's dive into the form issue. In your opinion, why am i better of NOT using a form, and why is it that form auto refreshes. Does 'post' ALWAYS refresh the page ? And where would I add 'e.preventDefault()' ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to give your button an id.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with some validation as well https://jsfiddle.net/tgq4vsdt/1/

```js
$(function(){
  $('#button').click(function(){
   if( $('input[name=checkListItem]').val().trim() != ""){
      var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
      $('.list').append('<div class="item">' + toAdd + '</div>');
    }
    $('input[name=checkListItem]').val('').focus();
  })
})
```

```css
.header, .form, h3, h4 {
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

hr {
  width: 50%;
  color: green;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: inset;
}

h3 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.container {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding-bottom: 3em;
  padding-top: 1em;
  width: 30%;
}

.item {
  color: black;
  font-size 18px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class='header'>
    <h1>Simple to-do list</h1>
    <h4>Simply type your item and click add</h4>
  </div>
  
  <div class='form'>
    <input type="text" name="checkListItem"/>
    <button class='btn btn-primary' id="button">Add!</button>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <h3>My to-do list</h3>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='list'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly does the validation do? Thank you

Comment: 1) If you try to enter blank todo item, it will stop you from adding... 2) It will not accept only spaces (without any character)...... 3) Once a item is added to the todo list it will clear the input text box and focus will go back to the input text box....